# Find the indefinite integral $\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx$$

**My attempt**:

$$I=\int\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx=\int x\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx=\\x\int \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx-\int \left[\frac{d}{dx}x\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx\right]dx$$

---

$I'=\displaystyle \int \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx$

Let $u=\cos x$

$\therefore \dfrac{du}{dx}=-\sin x$

$\implies du=(-\sin x)dx$

$\therefore \displaystyle I'=-\int \frac{du}{1+u^2} $

$\implies I'=-\dfrac{1}{1}\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{u}{1}\right)+C \implies I'=-\tan^{-1}(u)+C$

$\implies I'=-\tan^{-1}(\cos x)+C$

$\therefore \displaystyle \int \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx=-\tan^{-1} (\cos x)+C$

---

$\therefore \displaystyle I=x\cdot[-\tan^{-1} (\cos x)]-\int [-\tan^{-1} (\cos x)] dx$

$\implies  \displaystyle I=-x \tan^{-1} (\cos x)+\int \tan^{-1} (\cos x)dx$

I cannot understand how to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(xsinx)%2F(1%2Bcos%5E2x)

Apparently, it's an extremely complex integral... where did you get it from? Any chance of typo?

Comment: Would you like to see the result?

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat, I was trying to do $\int^{\pi}_0 \frac{x \sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}dx$ but without limits.

Comment: @MrAP it is usually a good idea to keep limits in if you are given them - some integrals simplify considerably with them.

Comment: @JohnDoe,  First i tried to evaluate the definite integral by trying to evaluate the indefinite integral first. When i was unable to do so, i used the properties of definite integrals and was able to evaluate it. Then i wondered how to integrate the indefinite integral and hence this question.

Comment: @MrAP: usually it is not a slick idea to *remove* the integration bounds and try to tackle a more difficult problem. Many integrals simplify by simmetry *because* the integration bounds are peculiar.

Answer (score 12):

I doubt you will be able to evaluate the integral without limits, since [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(xsin+x)%2F(1%2Bcos%5E2+x)+dx) shows that the integral is very complicated, and has polylogarithms.

With the limits given and using your progress so far, $$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}\,dx&=\left[-x\tan^{-1}(\cos x)\right]_0^\pi+\int_0^\pi\tan^{-1}(\cos x)\,dx\\&=\frac{\pi^2}4-\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1}(\sin x)\,dx\end{align}$$The second term is an integral of an odd function on a symmetric interval about $0$. So it is zero. Therefore the answer is $\frac{\pi^2}4$.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this in response to the comment by the OP that he/she actually was trying to solve the definite integral over $[0, \pi]$.

Using the fact that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(b + a - x) dx$$

we find

\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x \sin x}{1 + \cos^{2}x} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi - x) \sin(\pi - x)}{1 + \cos^{2}(\pi - x)} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi - x) \sin x}{1 + \cos^{2}x} dx \\
&= \pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{1 + \cos^{2} x} dx - I \\
\implies I &= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin x}{1 + \cos^{2}x} dx \qquad \text{(use substitution $u = \cos(x)$ to evaluate)} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\
&= \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}
\end{align}