# GRE subject math tough integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck on the integral.

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{1+ \cos^2x} dx$$

The hint was to swap limits and add something to cancel the $x$ out? If the denominator was $1 - \cos^2x$ we'd be in business lol.

Comment: This integral has a [horrible exact form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bx*sin%28x%29%2C1%2BPower%5Bcos%28x%29%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D), and evaluating it (according to Wolfram) from $0$ to $\pi$ gives $\pi^2/4$

Comment: If there was no $\;x\;$ in the numerator, as they hint, you'd be in business as you'd have an integral of the form $\;\int\frac{f'}{1+f^2} dx=\arctan f\;$ ...in fact, having$\;1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x\;$ in the denominator would render a rather horrible integral...

Comment: @FShrike but how do do it without Wolfram lol I'm studying for GRE subject math this came up on U of Chi practice probems

Comment: @DonAntonio so what do I do lol as there is an x. any idea on how to do this one

Comment: Keep the following in mind: GRE problems are by and large not overly difficult. They may however involve a trick to reduce them to something much simpler. Symmetries (such as $x\mapsto \pi-x$) are a good thing to try if you think the problem is very difficult at face value.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I was told this problem set is by far the most difficult its from uni of Chicago math department. im doing week 3 atm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\int^{\pi}_0\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608052/evaluate-int-pi-0-fracx-sinx1-cos2xdx)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608052/evaluate-int-pi-0-fracx-sinx1-cos2xdx?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762577/integrate-frac-theta-sin-theta1-cos2-theta-with-respect-to-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323109/integrating-int0-pi-fracx-sin-x1-cos2-x?noredirect=1&lq=1),[and this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736835/find-the-indefinite-integral-fracx-sin-x1-cos2-x?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: And more duplicates: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065659/evaluate-int-0-pi-fracx-sin-x1-cos2x-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061277/why-can-we-redefine-the-definition-of-a-variable-during-substitution-or-let-say?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I have added an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4228138). I haven't looked through all the answers to all the duplicates to see if this is the same as another answer, but it is different than the ones I've seen so far.

Comment: The answer I added is almost the same as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2736871).

Comment: @robjohn: This answer is identical to the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608052/evaluate-int-pi-0-fracx-sinx1-cos2xdx?noredirect=1&lq=1),  it is also the same as the answer provided by Harish [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762577/integrate-frac-theta-sin-theta1-cos2-theta-with-respect-to-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the answer provided by mattos [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736835/find-the-indefinite-integral-fracx-sin-x1-cos2-x?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The same technique is also shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801896/problematic-integral-int-0-pi-fracx-sin-x1-cos2x-dx/801899#801899) and in both of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065659/evaluate-int-0-pi-fracx-sin-x1-cos2x-mathrm-dx).

Comment: @Axion004: are you talking about the answer to this question or the  [answer I added](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4228138)? I found only [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2736871) that was close to the answer I added.

Comment: Your answer is different than all of the others. The accepted answer below is the same as the approach in the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Denote by $$I := \int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)^2}dx. $$

With the change of variables $x = \pi - t$, we get that $$I = \int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi - t) \sin(\pi - t)}{1 + \cos(\pi-t)^2}dt. $$

As $\sin(\pi-t) = \sin(t)$ and as $\cos(\pi - t) = -\cos(t)$, we have that $$I = \int_0^\pi \frac{(\pi - t) \sin(t)}{1 + \cos(t)^2}dt = \pi \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(t)}{1 + \cos(t)^2}dt - I, $$ and so $$I = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(t)}{1 + \cos(t)^2}dt. $$

The last integral can be computed using the change of variable $\cos(t) = y$, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: $dx=-dt$ so I think the sign of the entire answer must be flipped

Comment: It is true that $dx = -dt$, but the change of variables $x = \pi - t$ flips the limits of integration, and these two cancel out.

Comment: Aha! Then this is a good answer with good technique. I wonder why it can't be generalised and Wolfram's monster is necessary for a general integral

Comment: It can be generalized to $$\int_a^b f(t)dt = \int_a^b f(a+b-t)dt. $$

Comment: I will be sure to use this technique in the future. Thank you

Comment: so after evaluating the integral ill get the desired result? @C_M

Comment: seriously this is a great trick

Comment: Yes, the final answer is $\pi^2/4$, as @FShrike mentioned in the comments.

Comment: This is an excellent, helpful answer. The last integral is almost immediate and wouldn't even require change of variables: the integrand is $\;\cfrac{f'}{1+f^2}\;$ , so the integral equals $\;\arctan f\;$ .... (chain rule backwards)

Comment: Such integrals are quite easy, imo, if you have enough experience.(+1)

Comment: @FShrike : (about Wolfram's complicated answer) This integral contains a special symmetry owing to the particular bounds from $0$ to $\pi$. The answer Wolfram gives is for generic limits, which may not be symmetric.

Comment: This is a reminder to refrain from answering low-quality questions. See [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).